# Melhor solução para Web service Rest

Tags: java, json, web-service, rest, código-aberto

Queria implementar um *Web Service* que fosse fornecer dados a plataformas móveis (Android e iOS), alguém sabe qual o melhor serviço que posso utilizar para tal?

Tinha preferência que fosse algo *open source*.

Estive a fazer umas pesquisas e encontrei RESTEasy e JBoss, mas como não conheço nada gostaria de começar com uma boa solução (grande potencial de crescimento).

Comment: Entretanto também encontrei -> Java RESTful Plugin for Eclipse

Comment: eu gosto muito do Jersey, já deu uma olhada nele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedro Simões, tecnicamente o ASP.NET Web Api é Open Source.
Neste caso você pode usar o [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) ou o [VS 2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx),
quanto a tutoriais para ASP.NET Web Api, você os encontra bem facil no Google.

Caso tenha gostado das ferramentas acima citadas e queira usar algo que tenha as suas origens no mundo Open Source, pode pensar no [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) com [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com), mas para tal, você pode vir a precisar do [NodeJS Tools to VS](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme)

Segue um pequeno guia sobre RESTful API usando ExpressJS: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

E caso tenha tenha gostado do que viu, pode até pensar em ler sobre o [EdgeJS](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/) e juntar os dois mundos.

Answer (score 2):

[Spark](http://sparkjava.com/)
Muito simples de usar

```
public static void main(String...args) {
   get("/umPath", (req, res) -> {
       //Regra de negocio
       return "resultado"
   });
}
```

[SpringBoot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)
Também muito simples, mas diferente do spark, deve ser criado um controller e anota-lo com @RestController

```
@ResController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class UmaClasseController {

    @RequestMapping("/umPath")
    @ResponseBody
    String ola() {
        //Regra de negocio
        return "Resultado";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(UmaClasseController.class, args);
    }
}
```

O bom desse do Spring é que se for colocado o tipo de retorno como um objeto  ou uma coleção de objeto ele já serializa para JSON.

[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)
Também é bom, mas requer mas algumas configurações, e pode ser usado junto com o SpringBoot, anotado com @Component.